# My custom key binding with some alphabetic key (ex, o) does not work

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

## What I want to do

I want to open the current directory (open .) with the keybinding Ctrl + O.
I checked that my input for the terminal is accepted by the readline program and it considers `~/.inputrc`.

## What I tried

First I fix my ~/.inputrc like

```
"\C-o": "open .\n"'
```

than run `bind -f ~/.inputrc`. But Ctrl + O does nothing.

However, if I configured `~/.inputrc` as below,

```
"\C-l": "open .\n"'
```

Ctrl + L opens finder.

What is my misunderstanding?

## Environment

OS: macOS Mojave 10.14.6

Comment: what does `bind -p | grep 'C-o'` reveal?

Comment: `bind -p | grep 'C-o'` show nothing.